# validating whether a element exists and has some specific value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

how to check the tag exists and the value is 'On' do something  in xsl

please correct me.,

```
<xsl:if test="$status and $status='On'">

 //do something

</xsl:if>
```

can we skip checking whether the tag exists and direclty check for the value.

```
<xsl:if test="$status='On'">

     //do something

    </xsl:if>
```

is it a correct practice.,

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete explanation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<xsl:if test="$status and $status='On'">`

The above is redundant, because if `$status='On'` then the boolean value of `$status` is true.

Therefore, the expression contained in the @test attribute of the above xslt instruction is equivalent to just: `$status='On'`, which is shorter.

**This completely answers the question**.

It seems to me that you want to test if `$status` **is defined** and then test for its value. This is not correct -- if a reference is made to an undefined xsl:variable, this causes an error as per the W3 XSLT specification.

Comment: @flash: Your question "to check the tag exists and the value is 'On'" could also imply that `$status` is the *name of an element* you want to check, not an actual string value. If this is the case, use `<xsl:if test="*[name() = $status and .='On']">`.

Answer (score 2):

you should use xpath expressions

```
<xsl:if test="/path/node = 'On'">

</xsl:if>
```

or is $status a xsl param?

Comment: then <xsl:if test="$status='On'">

     //do something

    </xsl:if>
 is correct

Comment: is it not necessary to check whether 'status' exists using '$status'

Comment: correct, thats not needed. you wont get any null exeception or something in xslt